# Create relative symlinks using absolute paths in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, symlink

I have a projects with the following structure:

```
project-root
├── some-dir
│   ├── alice.json
│   ├── bob.json
│   └── dave.json
└── ...
```

I want to create symlinks like the following ones:

- `foo` -> `alice.json`

I chose to use the [`fs.symlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlink_srcpath_dstpath_type_callback) function:

> #### `fs.symlink(srcpath, dstpath[, type], callback)`
>
> Asynchronous symlink(2). No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback. The `type` argument can be set to `'dir'`, `'file'`, or `'junction'` (default is `'file'`) and is only available on Windows (ignored on other platforms). Note that Windows junction points require the destination path to be absolute. When using `'junction'`, the destination argument will automatically be normalized to absolute path.

So, I did:

```
require("fs").symlink(
  projectRoot + "/some-dir/alice.json"
, projectRoot + "/some-dir/foo"
, function (err) { console.log(err || "Done."); }
);
```

This creates the `foo` symlink. However, since the paths are absolute the symlink uses absolute path as well.

How can I make the symlink path relative to a directory (in this case to `some-dir`)?

This will prevent errors when the parent directories are renamed or the project is moved on another machine.

The dirty alternative I see is using `exec("ln -s alice.json foo", { cwd: pathToSomeDir }, callback);`, but I would like to avoid that and use the NodeJS API.

So, how can I make relative symlinks using absolute paths in NodeJS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Option 1: Use `process.chdir()` to change the current working directory of the process to `projectRoot`.  Then, provide relative paths to `fs.symlink()`.

Option 2: Use `path.relative()` or otherwise generate the relative path between your symlink and its target. Pass that relative path as the first argument to  `fs.symlink()` while providing an absolute path for the second argument. For example:

```
var relativePath = path.relative('/some-dir', '/some-dir/alice.json');
fs.symlink(relativePath, '/some-dir/foo', callback);
```

Comment: Might this be a situation where you would want the entire process to have `projectRoot` as the working directory anyway?

Comment: Yes and no - it's fine when using it as command line tool, but also, this tool I develop can be used as library. That's why I don't like setting the current working directory of the `process`.

Comment: OK, the alternative is to use `path.relative()`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: The second solution looks better. Could you please add an example as well?

Comment: Whoops, I had a small error in the example code. Just updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75849/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-trott).

Comment: @Trott: Could you please edit Option2 to this correct solution?: `fs.symlink(source, path.join(dir, target), 'file', function (err) {...});`, where `source = 'alice.txt', target = 'alice_symlink.txt', dir = './project-root/some-dir'`. Thank you.

Comment: Why? What does that answer provide that is missing or incorrect in the current answer?

Comment: I'm writing a CLI app and not sure my path back to the source which is inside the process dir. It will be run from various places, am looking at option 1. Perhaps I will store the current CWD and then restore it by changing back to users CWD.... sound OK?

Comment: Using `process.chdir()`, especially inside a general use module, seems like something that could cause unintended consequences, and thus probably shouldn't be used if it doesn't have to be....  might even be a good thing to make sure doesn't exist inside a codebase, as a general guideline...... unless it is used in a "top level" module or in some sort of isolated process that you don't intend to allow other processes to alter the node.js sequence of.

Answer (score 4):

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// The actual symlink entity in the file system
const source = /* absolute path of source */;

// Where the symlink should point to
const absolute_target = /* absolute path of target */;

const target = path.relative(
    path.dirname(source),
    absolute_target
);

fs.symlink(
    target,   
    source,
    (err) => {

    }
);
```